# VNC client like x2vnc

Tags: display, mouse, remote-desktop, screen-sharing, dual-screen

[x2vnc](https://fredrik.hubbe.net/x2vnc.html) is a program that lets you use two screens on two different computers as if they were connected to the same computer.

The overall result is that it works like a dual-display workstation, where the mouse pointer can pass from one screen to the other by trespassing a screen's edge.

<s>But x2vnc is only for a X11 server.</s> EDIT: But x2vnc is not compatible with macOS' screen sharing VNC server.

Is there any VNC client like this for macOS?

Or what's the closest I can get with existing VNC clients?

Answer (score 1):

xQuartz is an open-source X windowing system for macOS. I managed to run x2vnc on my mac:

1. Install [xQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org).
2. Download [x2vnc](https://fredrik.hubbe.net/x2vnc.html).
3. Within the x2vnc directory, run `./configure`
4. Edit the Makefile to include X11 (sorry I don't know the more elegant way to do this)

   - On line 7, add `-I/opt/X11/include` making the full line `INCLUDES = -I/opt/X11/include -I. -DVERSION=\"$(VERSION)\"`
   - On line 16, add `-L/opt/X11/lib` making the full line `LDLIBS=-L/opt/X11/lib -lX11 -lm`

     5. `make` and `sudo make install`

Comment: `./configure --x-includes=/opt/X11/include --x-libraries=/opt/X11/lib` without manually editing makefiles

Comment: unfortunately x2vnc is not compatible with macOS' screen sharing VNC server. what I get when connecting to it is: `VNC server supports protocol version 3.889 (viewer 3.3)` `VNC connection failed: Incompatible Version.`